# Getting libraries for my project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Trying to create simple project with JNA. I have added lines

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
```

But of course Eclipse is not happy since I don't have JNA installed. Now I could go to JNA site to download library for my Java version. But I have heard there is another way that allows make this automatically. I also need to somehow create application distribution with all libraries. What are these methods and how to create such project with Eclipse?

Comment: Get familiar with "Maven". Create a Maven project and add the dependencies from the pom.xml file. Read up on it, it is worth it in the long run.

Comment: Take a look at [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or the m2e eclipse plugin. You can copy and paste 5 lines of xml, and the dependencies are downloaded automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Modern Java (and other JVM language) applications use a dependency management tool, rather than manually managing dependencies. The two most prominent are [Gradle](https://gradle.org/whygradle-build-automation/) and [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/). Those two provide basically the same functions, which is much more than just dependency management - they're fully-fledged build management tools. Gradle uses Groovy as it's build language while Maven uses XML. Both have good integration into Eclipse.

If, however, you don't want to go that far, you can just download the JNA JAR(s) and add them to your project's build path (right-click the project and select **Properties**, then find your way to the build path section. There is plenty of help online).

Comment: Adding my two cents here - Maven is often easier to use for quick and simple stuff, since tons of Java libraries don't just have Maven support, they have the exact maven xml you need prominently posted on their download page. Gradle has support, but not like that.

Comment: My experience is different, @Jeutnarg - even maven.org's search site includes Gradle snippets. But once you have a dependencies section set up in your Gradle script it's trivial to add a new one if you know the goupId, artifactId, and version.

Comment: For me, it's with things like Mockito and gson, where there is a maven link on the front page - http://mockito.org/ and https://github.com/google/gson. It's not that Gradle isn't supported or is inferior, it's just that (imo) Maven is more visible, and that can make a big difference when you aren't sure where to look. I think the Mockito page is the best example of that, since Maven gets a link in the dead center of the landing page, but Gradle gets its mention a two screens down.